# Telerik Reporting - Passing object to UriReportSource Html5 reporting

Tags: html, reporting-services, telerik, telerik-reporting

I'm wondering how to passing the object data source into html5 report viewer.
I have view like this:

```
@{
    var theData = new UriReportSource();
    theData.Uri = "TestingReport.trdx";
    //this is should passing the data right?
    theData.Parameters.Add("passing", Model.pasing);
    theData.Parameters.Add("anotherPassing", Model.another);
}

@(
  Html.TelerikReporting().ReportViewer()
  .TemplateUrl("../ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.html").Id("ReportId")
  .ReportSource(theData)
  .ViewMode(ViewModes.PRINT_PREVIEW)
  .ScaleMode(ScaleModes.SPECIFIC)
  .Scale(1.0)
  .ServiceUrl("/api/reports/")
)
```

I already wired up the .trdx report into object data source.

And [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/html5-report-viewer-howto-custom-parameters.html) documentation is not helping, it's use TypeDataSource.

Answer (score 1):

```
.ServiceUrl() is what your looking for.
```

Url.Content("/api/reports/") is what Telerik has in their examples as the argument to ServiceUrl.  It assumes the api is implemented in the same application as the client (viewer).

To go across domains the server has to apply CORS to the API 
e.g.
.ServiceUrl(Url.Content("(prefix + server):9176/api/reports/"))`  (a different web api application on localhost)  is the call to make on the client.